# How to put menu bar in Apple menu bar in Mac OS by C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I found an example using the `TMenuBar.UseOSMenu` property to place a main menu for Windows and Mac.  But it seems it is only for Delphi.  I can't find the same property in FMX's `TMenuBar` component in C++Builder.

Does anyone know how to put a menu bar in Apple's menu bar on Mac OSX in C++?

I'm using C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `UseOSMenu` property in 10.1 Berlin, in Delphi or C++.  It was removed in XE3:

[New Units and Changes in FireMonkey XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Introducing_the_FireMonkey_Library#New_Units_and_Changes_in_FireMonkey_XE3)

> **UseOSMenu has been removed**. For multi-platform applications, you should use [`FMX.Menus.TMainMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Menus.TMainMenu), a nonvisual component

Also See:

[Using Menus in a FireMonkey Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Menus_in_a_FireMonkey_Application)

> Creating Menus for OS X and Windows
>
> Use the correct control for your target system (OS X vs. Windows).
>
> - For Windows applications, use the [`TMenuBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Menus.TMenuBar) control:
>
>   - The main menu is placed in the client area of the form (standard for Windows).
>   - The menu items are not on the Mac OS X menu bar (nonstandard for OS X).
> - For Mac OS X applications, use the [`TMainMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Menus.TMainMenu) component:
>
>   - The main menu is placed in the non-client area of the Windows form (nonstandard for Windows).
>   - Menu items are placed on the Mac OS X menu bar (standard for OS X).

Comment: Thanks, Remy. It works fine to use TMainMenu on the Mac OS X.

Comment: Hi Remy, do you know how to disable/hide TMainMenu when application is for Windows? My application is expected to be used for Mac OS X and Windows. For above comment, I need to use "TMenuBar" for Windows and "TMainMenu" for Mac OS X. I can hide "TMenuBar" when it runs in Mac OS X but I can't hide "TMainMenu" when it runs on Windows. And if I only uses "TMainMenu" for both OS, sometimes it reported error exception at run-time in Windows. Is it possible to use "TmainMenu" on Mac OS X and Windows? Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue. This is an area where using per-platform Views usually makes sense, except that you can't have per-platform components in separate Views, which I think is really stupid. And the whole point of FireMonkey is to write code once and use across platforms, so why is there not one menu component that behaves accordingly on each platform? I don't know. you will likely have to resort to `$IFDEF`s to dynamically create each menu component when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Resorting to $IFDEF and building the menus in code would work.  But it's odd that FMX doesn't handle the main menu in a more portable way.

As is, TMainMenu isn't too bad, with some hiccups:  On the Mac, the first defined menu becomes the application menu, with the name you gave it replaced by the app name.  So, it's necessary to create first menu with a dummy name (e.g., "App"), with the usual "About" command on that menu.  Then the File menu is the *second* menu to be defined.  When run on a PC, that first dummy "App" menu needs to be deleted in code or else it will display.  On the Mac (but not on PC) FMX adds an unrequested "Window" menu as the last menu; I have no idea how to prevent that.

An additional problem is ShortCuts. I haven't found a way to set these in TMainMenu's Items Editor in a portable way, i.e., resulting in Ctrl on PC and Cmd on Mac.  Oh well, maybe after all the only good solution really is to construct it all in code with completely separate TMenuBar and TMainMenu and $IFDEFs!